# Mobile container for Blazor web application

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, blazor

I have a existing Blazor Web Application. Is there a possibility to convert this in a mobile application?
Like a mini-browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use look at these:

[Hybrid Blazor apps in the Mobile Blazor Bindings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/hybrid-blazor-apps-in-mobile-blazor-bindings-july-update/)

[GitHub sample repo](https://github.com/xamarin/MobileBlazorBindings)